# How to empty S3 bucket using AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to empty an S3 bucket using CLI.

1. I tried `aws s3 rm --recursive` command which doesn't empty my bucket as it has versioned enabled.
2. I tried `aws s3 rb --force` command to forcefully delete the bucket, which doesn't work as well. It throws this error `BucketNotEmpty: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.`

I really need to get this done using CLI. Is there a way to do it. Please help. The end goal is to delete the bucket. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can only use the CLI try this:

```
aws s3api delete-objects \
  --bucket ${bucket_name} \
  --delete "$(aws s3api list-object-versions \
  --bucket "${bucket_name}" \
  --output=json \
  --query='{Objects: Versions[].{Key:Key,VersionId:VersionId}}')"
```